# Origin pole in type II compensator using OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, compensation

I am reading about *Type II Compensator Using Op-Amp* from the application report [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva662/slva662.pdf) (page 4).

From the transfer function (4), we can see that there is an origin pole, \$f_{p0}\$. However, the formula (8) implies that \$f_{p0}\$ is created by R1 and C1 not origin pole.

Is this a mistake?

[image]

Comment: R4 is also missing from the TF.

Comment: No, R4 doesn't have any influence on transfer function because virtual ground of OpAmp.

Comment: @anhnha and your problem is where ? Simply for the op amp case R1 and C1 sets the 0-dB crossover frequency.

Comment: @G36: From the application note, fp0 is the location of the origin pole not 0-dB crossover frequency.

Comment: fp0 is the location of origin pole while the formula (8) says a totally different thing. (8) implies that fp0 location is at 1/(2*pi*R1*C1) not zero.

Comment: I disagree with what you say. For exampel if we set R1 = 1k Ohm and C1 = 1.6uF we will have 0-dB at 100Hz but gain at 1Hz is 40dB. And for R1 = 1k ohm and C1 = 16uF we will have 0-dB at 10Hz and the gain at 1Hz equal to 20dB. Do the maths and you will see.  H(s) = (1+R2*C1*s)/((R1*C1*s)*(1+R2*C3*s))

Comment: So, if the Aol is 40dB (DC gain) the origin pole will be at 1Hz for (1k; 1.6uF) and at 0.1Hz (for 1K 16uF); Because this circuit at low frequency behaviours just like an op amp based integrator.

Comment: @G36: I tried to consider fp0 as crossover frequency and solved for fp0 but the expression is very complex. It is a function of of all components except R4 not just R1, C1 as the formula above.

Comment: I have just recognized what fp0 they are talking about. The transfer function denominator with s can be written as s/fp0. That is what fp0 the application note meant. I have a hard time to understand that as the application note doesn't make it clear. fp0 = 1/(2*pi *R1*(C1+C3)) that approximates 1/(2*pi * R1*C1) because C1 >> C3.

Comment: @G36: you are right! fp0 is the approximation of 0dB crossover frequency of the compensator. I have just plotted and checked it.